# Some words in Arabic appear calligraphic in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, arabic

It seems that Swing auto decorate some Arabic words by making them look some kind calligraphic. One of those words is Muhammad which is spelled in Arabic as محمد.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestProject extends JFrame {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestProject frame = new TestProject();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public TestProject() {
        this.setSize(200, 100);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("محمد");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 28));
        this.add(label);
    }

}
```

The problem is applied to all widely used Fonts at least.

I'm using Windows 10 & Java 8. I've tried the same program on another PC (also Windows 10) same problem.

[image]

How can we disable that?

Comment: Recent experiments rendering a (nonsense) Arabic word suggested to me that it was mostly down to the `Font` being used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The problem is not related to a specific `Font`.

Comment: @BuSaeed You should explain in your Question why you can exclude fonts as an issue.

Comment: FYI, I copy-pasted your string `محمد` [to IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/zrHSd3). It seems to reproduce.

Comment: @BasilBourque The issue occurs with Swing GUI. Try to type `محمد` inside a JTextField or any other Component.

Comment: *"Try to type.."* Try to render the `String` in every `Font` the system has, which claims to be able to support those characters. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The problem is same with all widely used Fonts. I've also updated my question. @AndrewThompson

Comment: Doesn't your own screenshot show the calligraphic rendering to be a result of the particular font? Your screenshot image seems to contradict your statement: “The problem is applied to all widely used Fonts at least.” For example, fonts KacstBook, KacstOffice, both Lucida, and the first two Noto seem to give what you want, whereas Times, Trad. Arabic, Aldhabi, and others render with the calligraphic effect. (Keep in mind I know nothing about Arabic.)

Comment: It seems fonts are rendered fine with Swing in macOS. Actually the fonts rendered correctly in Windows are not the most used ones and they cannot be used in many situations. For example I've been recently working on an accounting application and believe me it's weird to use KacstBook with an invoice JTable. Usually Arial is used in such case. @BasilBourque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the old (i.e. up to Java 8) font rendering engine.

This is how it looks with Java 8 on my machine:

[image: Font rendering with Java 8]

And this is the result with Java 9:

[image: Font rendering with Java 9]

I don’t know whether an explicit bug report has been reported for this specific issue. But the font engine has been replaced entirely, due to [JEP 258: HarfBuzz Font-Layout Engine](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064530).

> Replace the existing ICU OpenType font-layout engine with HarfBuzz.

So it’s not surprising that bugs of the old font rendering are gone.

Comment: After using Java 11 the problem has gone.

Answer (score 4):

(Caveat: I am not literate in Arabic.)

## Appears to be font related

By default, I do not get your longer representation (3 words?) as seen in your screenshot.

- When I write a minimal Swing app with the text `"محمد"` I get that short string (4 characters?) that you want.
- When using specific fonts, I do get what looks to my untrained eye to be the calligraphic rendering you seek to avoid.

Note that my string was *not* your string. I copied from *Google Translate*, translating `Muhammad` as indicated in your Question.

```
https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ar&text=Muhammad%0A&op=translate
```

I wrote this minimal Swing app with just a `JLabel`, enhanced only by increasing font size.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( Runtime.version() );
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated( true );

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test Arabic rendering" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel( "محمد" );
        label.setFont( new Font( label.getFont().getName() , label.getFont().getStyle() , 40 ) );  // Override default font size.
        System.out.println( "Font name: " + label.getFont().getName() + "  |  " + "Font style: " + label.getFont().getStyle() );
        frame.getContentPane().add( label );

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

When run on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), Apple Silicon (not Intel), 16 gigs of memory. The OS is macOS Big Sur, 11.5.1. Using early-access version of Java 17 (17+35-2724) from [this page](http://jdk.java.net/17/).

[image: Screenshot of minimal Swing app with Arabic text.]

(By the way, this is the kind of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you should have posted with your Question.)

The result of my font query is:

> Font name: Lucida Grande  |  Font style: 0

… but I suspect that is the default font of the `JLabel` widget rather than the actual font used in rendering those Arabic characters. As I vaguely recall, recent versions of macOS are rich with a variety of fonts specifically for Arabic. See: [*Fonts included with macOS Big Sur*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211240) for three lists: fonts included, fonts available for download, and older fonts available for document support. Using the [*Font Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_Book) app bundled with macOS, and defining a "smart collection" where languages include Arabic, I get a list of 32 such fonts installed by default in macOS Big Sur. (The four items for [Pragmata Pro](https://fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro/) do not apply — that is a commercial font which I purchased, and which I highly recommend for developers.)

[image: screenshot of Font Book app showing list of 32 fonts bundled]

I ran this modified version of the code from [Answer by Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68769267/642706) on the same macOS Big Sur described above.

```java
package work.basil.text;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProject extends JFrame {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        TestProject frame = new TestProject();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public TestProject () {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        this.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        String input = "محمد";
        String[] fontFamilies = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for ( String fontFamily : fontFamilies ) {
            Font font = new Font( fontFamily , Font.PLAIN , 40 );
            if ( font.canDisplayUpTo( input ) < 0 ) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel( input );
                label.setFont( font );
                label.setBorder( new TitledBorder( fontFamily ) );
                this.add( label );
            }
        }

        this.pack();
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result.

[image: screenshot of same Arabic text shown in all fonts that supposedly can handle that phrase]

Comment: Plus one! Out of curiosity, how does Helvetica render the characters? On my Windows based system, [Arial (sometimes referred to as the 'poor cousin' of Helvetica) seems to have defaulted to *Times New Roman*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxAzS.jpg) for Arabic strings.

Comment: @AndrewThompson (A) Because the text is rendered within Swing, presumably with automatic font selection by the host macOS, there is no way for me to determine what font is actually being used for display of the rendered Arabic characters. (B) I tried using *Web Developer Tools* of Firefox Developer Edition to identify the font used by the [IdeOne.com page](https://ideone.com/zrHSd3) I linked in a Comment. But no go, I do not know how to properly used that tool, and it seems the content of the page is nested in `iframe` elements that I cannot peruse.

Comment: @AndrewThompson (C) In Safari 14, I tried Develop > Show Web Inspector. There the element with the Arabic text has id of `"output-text"`. The inspector showed the `pre` element as using a font-stack of `Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;`. But I do not know how the see the *actual* font being used for display of those characters. I suspect macOS is using another font for the Arabic, but that is just a guess. I suppose one of those fonts might have Arabic glyphs, but I do not know for sure either way.

Comment: The problem is same with all widely used Fonts and all components in Swing. I've also updated my question. @BasilBourque

Comment: Could yo do me a solid? Run the code in my answer and provide the screenshot. I'm still interested in what Helvetica renders for that string.. And while we're at it, every other font on the system which offers glyphs for those characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done. See bottom of my Answer for code and screenshot. I had to switch to `FlowLayout` from `GridLayout`. Nice tip about [`Font#canDisplayUpTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplayUpTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: *"Done."* Thanks! Yeah Helvetica did a much better job on rendering that..

Answer (score 1):

Try running the code below. It produced this image on my range of installed fonts.

Note also that Arial (a sans-serif or undecorated font) seems to default to Times New Roman (a serif or decorated font) for its Arabic glyphs. This is a common thing for fonts (or systems, not sure) to do, and it produces rather odd renderings when sans-serif fonts are replaced with serif fonts.

[image]

Also note this system has 255 fonts installed, but only 23 of those support Arabic characters.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TestProject extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestProject frame = new TestProject();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TestProject() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5));
        String arabic = "محمد";
        String[] fontFamilies = GraphicsEnvironment.
                getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for (String fontFamily : fontFamilies) {
            Font font = new Font(fontFamily, Font.PLAIN, 25);
            if (font.canDisplayUpTo(arabic) < 0) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(arabic);
                label.setFont(font);
                label.setBorder(new TitledBorder(fontFamily));
                p.add(label);
            }
        }
        this.add(new JScrollPane(p));
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Check it out please.

Comment: *"How can we disable that?"* You just don't seem to be *getting it.* There is nothing here that needs, or *should*, be disabled. **Use. A. Font. That. Works.**

Comment: But the same Font let's take Arial for instance doesn't appear the same when I use it in NotePad, MS Word or etc.

Comment: *"But the same Font.."* Will not even be available on a Mac. Stop futzing about and find and use one that works as you expect. Supply it with the app. if need be. Declare it be used in the `UIManager` or a custom PLAF. I'm not investing effort in figuring out why Windows behaves differently between apps, for their rendering of a Windows specific font. It's a waste of time.